# Cannot find -lftd2xx when attempting to build a 32-bit JD2XX DLL

Tags: java, usb, mingw, driver, 32-bit

I'm trying to build a 32-bit DLL of the JD2XX project found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/d2xx/. I'm using MinGW to compile the code but am receiving an error from ld.exe stating that it "cannot find -lftd2xx".  I was wondering if anyone has seen/fixed this issue before or has any ideas on how I might be able to fix this problem.

I have gotten this error when trying to build this on both 64-bit win7 and a 32-bit xp machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out what the issue was, and it makes me feel kind of silly.  But to anyone trying to build this project and is running into a similar issue here's the fix.

The Makefile for the JD2XX dll has a line in it that reads:
     LIB = -L$(FTDI) -lftd2xx

This needs to be changed instead to:
     LIB = -L$(FTDI)/$(ARCH) -lftd2xx